# sendto pid and groups

Tags: linux, udp, system-calls, strace, sendto

I'm trying to understand this line from an strace on linux:

```
sendto(10, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3\233\274\362O\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
```

I have looked on the net and in man pages about sendto, but I see no reference of pid and groups. event AF_NETLINK is not mentioned.

What do the pid and groups arguments mean? Where can I find the right doc about this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That argument is a `struct sockaddr *`, as per the [`sendto`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) manual page. When used with [`netlink`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) sockets, it's actually a `struct sockaddr_nl`:

```
struct sockaddr_nl {
       sa_family_t     nl_family;  /* AF_NETLINK */
       unsigned short  nl_pad;     /* Zero. */
       pid_t           nl_pid;     /* Process ID. */
       __u32           nl_groups;  /* Multicast groups mask. */
};
```

So that's where the `pid` and `groups` must be coming from (the "Address Formats" section of the manual explains those fields).

Answer (score 0):

The right doc is `man 7 netlink` but netlink does a lot of obscure stuff that isn't extremely well documented so good luck.